# Can an iOS/Android application be a consumer of AWS Kinesis?

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, consumer

I am trying to build a ride hailing system and there is a need to show driver's location in real time fashion on the rider's application. Currently, I'm using AWS Kinesis as the platform to send driver's location streaming data.

I have gone through AWS Kinesis document but unfortunately, I could not find a function for iOS and/or Android to register as a consumer of the data stream. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. AWS Kinesis would feed into other systems which would eventually provide processed info to your website/mobile device. How to do such a thing would be too broad for StackOverflow. For example see: https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/lyft/

Answer (score -1):

You can check out the AWS iOS SDK's over at https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios

AWS Kinesis SDK - https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/tree/master/AWSKinesis